# show that $\mathbb{K}[x_1,...,x_n]$ is a subset of $C(\mathbb{K}^n,\mathbb{K})$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, general-topology, topological-vector-spaces

I do not understand very well the following text which shows what I ask, if you could help me understand it I would appreciate it.

"We have, then, that if $X$ is a topological space, then $C(X,\mathbb{K})$ is a $k$-algebra of functions. The space $C(X,\mathbb{K})$ contains an isomorphic subbody a $\mathbb{K}$, namely, the space of constant functions. When there is no confusion we will identify the constant functions with the elements of $\mathbb{K}$, so that, for example, $2$ will represent the function that takes the value $2$ over all points of $X$.

Furthermore, if $p(x_1,...,x_n)\in \mathbb{K}[x_1,...,x_n]$, the polynomial p determines a unique evaluation function $p:\mathbb{K}^n→\mathbb{K}$, so that the constant polynomials correspond to the constant functions and the indeterminate $x_i$ to the projection on the $i$-th coordinate. Since every polynomial is a combination of sums and products of constants and indeterminates, we can conclude that $\mathbb{K}[x_1,...,x_n]\subset C(\mathbb{K}^n,\mathbb{K})$"

Comment: $\mathbb{K}$ is $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$? Also, in english we commonly call cuerpos by 'fields'

Comment: Exactly, it is one of those 2 options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simple: sum and product are continuous functions from $\mathbb{K}^2$ to $\mathbb{K}$, as well as constant functions, projections, and the function $(f,g): \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m \times \mathbb{R}^k$ for $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m, g: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^k$ continuous. Because every polynomial is a combination of compositions of these functions and the composition of continuous functions must again be continuous, polynomials must be continuous.

For example, consider $p(x_1, x_2) = x_1x_2 + x_2^2 \in \mathbb{K}[x_1, x_2]$. Writing $\pi_i$ as the projection projection in the $i$-th coordinate, and $S, P$ as the sum and product, respectively, then we can write the evaluation map $p: \mathbb{K}^2 \to \mathbb{K}$ as $S(P(\pi_1, \pi_2), P(\pi_2, \pi_2))$ - which is a composition of continuous functions.

The argument could be properly arranged into an inductive argument on the degree of the polynomial, however I think it would just make thing more compllicated.

Comment: I am understanding, but two things are still difficult for me in your answer. The first, is what is the function $(f, g)$? The second, the projection function $\pi_i$ is the projection function with what domain and range?

Comment: Oh, another question. The order of $P$ and $S$ is ok?

Comment: The function $(f,g)$ is the function defined by $x \mapsto (f(x), g(x))$.  The domain of $\pi_i$ is $\mathbb{K}^n$, with range $\mathbb{K}$. What do you mean by the order of $P, S$?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers, I have almost understood. I only have one last question regarding your answer. When you mentioned : "...$P$,$S$ as the sum and product, respectively..." .Is the order of $P,S$ correct?

Comment: No, it isn't. Fixed it.

Comment: It was the only question I had pending in your answer, thank you very much. It has become clear.